# add product title & short desc into product tabs

Tags: php, magento, product, magento2

I am trying to add the product title and short description within the product tabs on the luma theme. With short description, I am happy to use the move object to place this into the tabs but I need to style it with a  tag, with the product title I want to replicate this so I will have it as a h1 and h3. Below is the code I have added to description.phtml but I cannot get this to render correctly

```
<h3><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getName())) ?></h3>
<h4><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($block->stripTags($block->getProduct()->getShortDescription())) ?></h4>
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `$block->getProduct()->getName()` would be enough, actually, since it is not a HTML attribute and also Magento seems to take care of escaping illegal characters ([reference](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/179235/how-to-get-product-name-in-phtml-file-in-magento2)).